# Rank of a linear map equalling dimension of the vector space implication question

Tags: linear-algebra

so this is what my textbook has to say regarding a linear map:

THEOREM. Where V is an n-dimensional vector space, these are equivalent statements about a linear map $h: V \rightarrow W$    (skip a few statements)

(4) rank(h) = n
(5) if $\langle \vec B_1, ..., \vec B_n \rangle$ is a basis for V then $\langle h(\vec B_1), ..., h(\vec B_n) \rangle$ is a basis for R(h) (R(h) means range space of h)

To prove that 4 implies 5, it states:

To show that $\langle h(\vec B_1), ..., h(\vec B_n) \rangle$ is a basis for the range space, we need only show that it is a spanning set, because by assumption the range has dimension n.

My question is: just because the range space has dimension n doesn't imply that it is linearly independent, no? I thought linear independence is only preserved if the mapping is an isomorphism, which wasn't specified at all by this theorem.

Comment: If $n$ things span a space of dimension $n$, then they must be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Gerry's comment: in general if $E$ is any $n$-dimensional vector space and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a list of $n$ vectors in $E$ which spans $E$, then we know that the list can be reduced to a basis of $E$ by throwing away zero or more vectors. However, any basis of $E$ must have $n$ vectors, so in the reduction we're throwing away zero vectors, which means the list $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is already a basis of $E$ and hence is linearly independent.